# IncompatibleClassChangeError while configuring spring3.0+thymeleaf+tiles2

Tags: thymeleaf, tiles2

While I was configuring my beans od spring3.0+thymeleaf+tiles2 i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in class com.spr.init.WebAppConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver com.spr.init.WebAppConfig.templateResolver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1031)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:927)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver com.spr.init.WebAppConfig.templateResolver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.html.AbstractHtmlTemplateParser$HtmlTemplateParserFactory.createResource(AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.java:227)
at org.thymeleaf.util.ResourcePool.<init>(ResourcePool.java:79)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.html.AbstractHtmlTemplateParser$NekoBasedHtmlParser.<init>(AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.java:136)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.html.AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.<init>(AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.java:75)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.html.LegacyHtml5TemplateParser.<init>(LegacyHtml5TemplateParser.java:45)
at org.thymeleaf.templatemode.StandardTemplateModeHandlers.<clinit>(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.java:103)
at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver.<clinit>(TemplateResolver.java:68)
at com.spr.init.WebAppConfig.templateResolver(WebAppConfig.java:104)
at com.spr.init.WebAppConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c91bdc02.CGLIB$templateResolver$4(<generated>)
at com.spr.init.WebAppConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c91bdc02$$FastClassByCGLIB$$75d7ea47.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
at com.spr.init.WebAppConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c91bdc02.templateResolver(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
... 29 more
```

and my WebAppConfig.java is given below

### WebAppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.spr")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.spr.repository")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

//Configuring a TemplateResolver

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
       ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){      
    ThymeleafTilesConfigurer configurer = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
    String[] tilepath = {"/WEB-INF/thymeleaftiles.xml"};
    configurer.setDefinitions(tilepath);
    return configurer;      

}   

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    Set tileset = new HashSet();
    tileset.add(TilesDialect.class);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.setAdditionalDialects(tileset);
    return engine;
}



@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);




resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;        
}   


@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename(env.getRequiredProperty("message.source.basename"));
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
}
```

I couldnt figure out where have i gone wrong and this is driving me crazy.Can anyone help me sort this thing out..

Comment: What version of xerces do you use? Which version of java ?

Comment: Im using 1.6 version of java